# After removing .bash_history?

Tags: bash, bash-history

After I remove .bash_history, will .bash_history ever be recreated again? If so what creates it after it has been removed?

Comment: Obvious question... why do you want to remove .bash_history?

Comment: In case I entered sensitive information??? Why do you have to know why I want to remove it.

Comment: Who else besides you could/would look at it? And... it remembers bash commands... not sensitive information... unless you're greping for strange text strings... or copying files with your password in the filename... etc...

Comment: What if I accidentally type sensitive info?

Comment: Is your computer shared with anybody else that has an admin account, or the root password?

Comment: Admin account. Root password is shared

Answer (score 4):

See the "invocation" section of bash's manual (`man bash`).

Put `set +o history` in either `/etc/profile`, `~/.bash_profile`,  `~/.bash_login`, `~/.profile`, or `~/.bashrc`.  The 1st one is for all users, and the others are for 1 user. `~/.profile` should always be there so use that one.

You still need to remove the current history file. `history -c` clears it but will leave an empty file so remove `~/.bash_history` with `rm`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know, what happens if you remove the file. I guess a new version will be created. If not, you can create it manually,

```
touch ~/.bash_history
```

Sometimes I happen to enter a password or other sensitive information incorrectly, so that it will be saved in the file `.bash_history`. Then I will edit the file and remove the sensitive information (the corresponding line(s)) and save the file. (Edit: I will close all terminal windows, set the file browser to show hidden files and start editing via the file browser.)

---

I want to keep the main part of the history, because it makes things easier, so I would not remove the file.

I have even made a couple of script files to search the bash history quickly with a search string as parameter.

HI (HIstory),

```
history|grep "$*" |sed 's/^ *//' |tr -s ' ' ' '|cut -d ' ' -f2-
```

HIT (HIstory Tail),

```
history|grep "$*" |sed 's/^ *//' |tr -s ' ' ' '|cut -d ' ' -f2- |tail
```

Comment: Alright, very useful first part.  But I really wasn't looking for what you said in the second part. I may use it though.

Comment: @NerdOfCode, You are right, you asked only for the first part (and the second part is separated by the horizontal line because of that). But it is useful for me, and I am happy to share it in this context, when talking about bash history :-)

Comment: Very useful information. I appreciate you putting in the extra time to help a fellow Ubuntu user out. :)